# Scipy sosfilt ValueError ndarray is not C-contiguous

Tags: numpy, filter, scipy, signal-processing, numpy-ndarray

`sosfilt` from the `scipy=1.9.3` library is giving me a strange ValueError when inputting a `numpy=1.23.4` array.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import sosfilt

fs=48000

rng = np.random.default_rng()
signal = rng.normal(size=(fs))

b_0k = [1.01589602025559, 0.958943219304445, 0.961371976333197,
        2.22580350360974, 0.471735128494163, 0.115267139824401,
        0.988029297230954, 1.95223768730136]
b_1k = [-1.92529887777608, -1.80608801184949, -1.76363215433825,
        -1.43465048479216, -0.366091796830044, 0.0, -1.91243380293387,
        0.162319983017519]
b_2k = [0.922118060364679, 0.876438777856084, 0.821787991845146,
        -0.498204282194628, 0.244144703885020, -0.115267139824401,
        0.926131550180785, -0.667994113035186]
a_0k = np.ones(len(b_0k))
a_1k = [-1.92529887777608, -1.80608801184949, -1.76363215433825,
        -1.43465048479216, -0.366091796830044, -1.79600256669201,
        -1.91243380293387, 0.162319983017519]
a_2k = [0.938014080620272, 0.835381997160530, 0.783159968178343,
        0.727599221415107, -0.284120167620817, 0.805837815618546,
        0.914160847411739, 0.284243574266175]

sos = np.array([b_0k, b_1k, b_2k, a_0k, a_1k, a_2k]).T

signalFiltered = sosfilt(sos, signal, axis=0)
```

gives me

signalFiltered = sosfilt(sos, signal, axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In[102], line 1
signalFiltered = sosfilt(sos, signal, axis=0)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\devenv\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal_signaltools.py:4247 in sosfilt
_sosfilt(sos, x, zi)

File _sosfilt.pyx:81 in scipy.signal._sosfilt._sosfilt

File stringsource:660 in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper

File stringsource:350 in View.MemoryView.memoryview.**cinit**

ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous

However

```
signal.flags
```

shows

C_CONTIGUOUS : True

F_CONTIGUOUS : True

OWNDATA : True

WRITEABLE : True

ALIGNED : True

WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False

I have also tried this on other signals imported from wav files, with the same error. Having looked around, there does not seem to be any known issue or other examples of this error using this function (although there are some machine learning package bugs discussed [elsewhere](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24013))

What is the problem with Scipy?

Comment: It's the transpose that's given problems, making it F contiguous. Add a `.copy()`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj - modified to `signalFiltered = sosfilt(sos.copy(order='C'), signal, axis=0)` gets it working. Would you like to add this as the answer? It would be great to have a little explanation as well, if you have time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the transpose that's giving problems, making it `F contiguous`. Add a `.copy()`.

Look at the array flags, before and after transpose and copy.

`transpose` works by reversing the strides and shape. It's a `view`, a cheap way of doing the job, but messes with the  continuity.